# Excel VBA: Formatting Based on The Format of Another Cell, Getting Method Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet that breaks out the tasks in a given department. Each task is then assigned to a person in that department using a data validation drop down that dynamically fetches values from the tables that list each employee/role in the department. The tables are on a different sheet than the task breakdown.

Each individual needs their own background color that automatically fills in when their name is selected from the drop down on the tasks sheet. What I'm hoping to do is write a macro that looks for that person's name in the table (note that I'm using named ranges) and then matches the formatting of the selected cell to their row in the table. I'm a super beginner with VBA and have hit the end of my abilities. Several answers that come close to what I want to do, but in terms of adapting it for my specific use case, I'm stuck.

I grabbed code from this thread, which is essentially the result I want to achieve, except that their key is on the same sheet and mine can't be: https://superuser.com/questions/472918/excel-conditionally-format-a-cell-using-the-format-of-another-content-matching

So far, I've compiled this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If VarType(Target) > vbArray Then Exit Sub
' if multiple cells are changed at once, then exit

Dim kr1 As Range
Dim kr2 As Range
Dim KeyRange As Range
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim lCell As Object
Dim kCell As Object

Set kr1 = Application.Range("ESFormattingRange")
Set kr2 = Application.Range("CSFormattingRange")
Set KeyRange = Application.Union(Range("kr1"), Range("kr2"))
' formatting key is here
Set TargetRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("A:X")
' changing cells in this area

For Each kCell In KeyRange.Cells
 If kCell.Value <> "" Then
  For Each lCell In TargetRange.Cells
    If lCell.Value = kCell.Value Then
    ' only change cells that match the edited cell
        lCell.Font.Color = kCell.Font.Color
        lCell.Interior.Color = kCell.Interior.Color
        ' copy whatever you feel needs to be copied
    End If
  Next
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the following method error, but no lines are highlighted when I try to debug:

> Compile error:
>   Method or data member not found

I'm thinking maybe there's something wrong with the way I've constructed my range variables, but I've googled everything I can think of and I'm at a loss.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing an `s` on the end of `Worksheet` in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("A:X")`.

Answer (score 0):

The VBE should be highlighting the word `Worksheet` in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("A:X")`.

"Method or data member not found" means `Worksheet` isn't a member of `ThisWorkbook`.

You can fix this by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to autocomplete the member name to `Worksheets`.

Alternatively, you can re-type the `.` dereferencing operator after `ThisWorkbook`, and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> when the names list dropdown is shown, highlighting the `Worksheets` member - that will also autocomplete the member name to `Worksheets`.

Rule of thumb, if you type a `.` dereferencing operator and then type something that isn't in the names list, you can expect this compile error.

When you make this typo against a `Variant` or `Object` variable, the code will happily compile, but error 438 will be thrown *at run-time* - like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Ragne("A:X") ' <~ typo compiles. Option Explicit can't save you.
```

The reason is that `Worksheets` returns an `Object` reference, so any member calls chained to it are resolved at run-time. A safer way to code is to declare a local `Worksheet` variable to hold this object, and then work with that object instead:

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

sourceSheet.Rnage("A:X") ' <~ typo throws at compile-time now!
```

If the worksheet object exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time however, then it's probably a better idea to work with its *code name* instead. Locate `Sheet3` in the *Project Explorer* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+R), then find its `(Name)` property - change it to e.g. `SourceSheet`. And then you can do this:

```
SourceSheet.Range("A:X") ' <~ a typo wouldn't compile here.
```

...without needing to explicitly declare a `SourceSheet`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did as suggested and used the code name to set the TargetRange variable, which got me past the error. And I was really excited for a second until I realized that the macro wasn't actually copying the formatting to the changed cell. It doesn't error out, but it doesn't do anything else either, as far as I can tell. Do you think the issue may be that while lCell and kCell are declared as Objects, they aren't set to the object type Cell?

Comment: @AnnaH there's no `Cell` type, a cell is a `Range`... and `Range.Cells` without parameters is redundant ;-)

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your patience :) That being said, any other advice as to what I might try to get the intended result? I don't really know what else to try...